# Estimating probabilities for model subset after grouping

Tags: r, grouping, subset, markov-chains

The data used is available [here](https://figshare.com/s/ace5b44bc12394a7c46d) (the file is called "figshare.txt").

I estimated the transition probabilities for a Markov model where the observations were grouped by location (`group_by(km)`).

```
data <- data %>% group_by(km) %>% summarize(pp_chain=list(pp)) %>% as.data.frame 
pp_chains <- data$pp_chain; names(pp_chains) <- data$km
fit <- markovchainFit(pp_chains)
```

The output (summarized here) shows the probability estimates for the model overall:

```
print(fit$estimate)
      0          1
0 0.9116832 0.08831677
1 0.5250852 0.47491476
```

Hypothetically, the output I am after would be more specific and would provide me with probabilities for each location (`km`).

It would look something like this:

```
km = 80
      0          1
0 0.7116832 0.28831677
1 0.1250852 0.17491476

km = 81
      0          1
0 0.8116832 0.18831677
1 0.4250852 0.37491476

km = 83
      0          1
0 0.6116832 0.38831677
1 0.3250852 0.27491476
```

> Does anyone know how to extract the Markov model estimates for each location (`km`) individually after the model is run?

Comment: I know dplyr is your flavor, maybe base R's `by` can help: `by(data, data$km, FUN=function(df) markovchainFit(df$pp))`

Comment: @Parfait That also gives me the solution I was looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would a simple `lapply()` solution suffice? As far as I understand each sequence is treated separately, i.e. no complicated interdependencies etc.?

```
library(dplyr)
library(markovchain)

data <- read.table(paste0("https://ndownloader.figshare.com/files",
  "/10412271?private_link=ace5b44bc12394a7c46d"), header=TRUE, sep="\t")

data <- data %>% group_by(km) %>% summarize(pp_chain=list(pp)) %>% as.data.frame 
pp_chains <- data$pp_chain; names(pp_chains) <- data$km

est <- lapply(pp_chains, function(x) markovchainFit(x)$estimate)
head(est, 3)

# $`80`
          # 0         1
# 0 0.8470588 0.1529412
# 1 0.7222222 0.2777778


# $`81`
          # 0         1
# 0 0.6976378 0.3023622
# 1 0.2107574 0.7892426


# $`83`
          # 0          1
# 0 0.9706840 0.02931596
# 1 0.4210526 0.57894737
```

Comment: That answer does offer me the solution I was looking for. Thank you!